# Searching for a JSON Object in a JSON Schema based on the name and getting the Path

Tags: go

I'm using JSON Schema and auto generating it using gojsonschema. Unfortunately, it's getting several of the fields wrong, and I want to fix them.

Here is the schema:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://github.com/filecoin-project/bacalhau/pkg/model/job",
  "$ref": "#/$defs/Job",
  "$defs": {
    "Deal": {
      "properties": {
        "Concurrency": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Confidence": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "MinBids": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "type": "object"
    },
    "Spec": {
      "properties": {
        "Engine": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
       "Verifier": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
      },
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do is find the path to a given field (in this case "Engine") programatically. This is so I can just list all the objects that need changing (they all need changing in the same way), and loop through them in an array. So something like this (which works today).

```golang
func FixJSONSchema() ([]byte, error) {
    s := jsonschema.Reflect(&model.Job{})

    jsonSchemaData, err := json.MarshalIndent(s, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error indenting %s", err)
    }

    // JSON String
    jsonString := string(jsonSchemaData)

    enumTypes := []struct {
        Name string
        Path string
    }{
        {Name: "Engine", Path: "$defs.Spec.properties.Engine.type"},
        {Name: "Verifier", Path: "$defs.Spec.properties.Verifier.type"},
    }
    for _, enumType := range enumTypes {
        // Use sjson to find the enum type path in the JSON
        jsonString, _ = sjson.Set(jsonString, enumType.Path, "string")

    }

    return []byte(jsonString), nil
}
```

I'm using the excellent sjson library to accomplish this. https://github.com/tidwall/sjson

So, in summary, what I'd really prefer to do, is just have an array `["Engine", "Verifier", ...]` and use a tool to search the entire structure and return the path (or paths if multiple things match).

Comment: Use a jsonpath library, there are some that will let you find such keys, like https://github.com/PaesslerAG/jsonpath

Comment: the issue i have is that all of these libraries (that i've found so far) allow me to get the value of the path. I want the path itself (imagine searching for both Concurrency and Engine (above) without knowing any of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly it seems like you are over-complicating the task. Using reflect is
rarely the right solution to any problem, instead you could use something like
Gron. Here it is with PowerShell:

```
> gron schema.json | Select-String engine
json.$defs.Spec.properties.Engine = {};
json.$defs.Spec.properties.Engine.type = "integer";
```

or POSIX shell:

```
gron schema.json | grep engine
```

https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron

Comment: Fascinating - didn't even think of this. It's perfect!

Comment: Oh rats - I thought the author had exported functions so I could use it. This isn't going to work because i need to stay in go.

Comment: @aronchick good luck to you. I don't have (and don't want) experience with reflect

Comment: haha - i didn't think this was a reflect issue (since it's just parsing JSON). but thanks for your help :)